# What was going with the family of Marquez?

Tags: estoy-vivo

At the beginning of the third season, Carlota delayed Laura, Susana, and Beatriz, thus assuring that they

> got hit by a truck and died.

In the recap at the beginning of the episode, they also mentioned the fact that the family of Marquez had died in a car accident on exactly the same day as Vargas. It seemed fairly obvious that Carlota had tried to kill them, and she was also been the same person who had killed the family of Marquez some time back.

Except, none of that was true. Carlota was not trying to kill pregnant women in order to kill Susana, but rather to eliminate the extraterrestrial invasion, possibly under orders from the conspiracy of Liasons that was working against the director. Susana had not even reincarnated as a pregnant woman, but rather in a male body. Carlota claims that she had been trying to *save* Susana. Moreover, not even the aliens were trying to kill Susana—they just wanted to collect their "babies." In the end, it seems that it was the mutiny of Liasons who were trying to get them killed, and they even arranged the car crash, telling Carlota that she would be trying to prevent it.

In short, all that explains the situation with Susana. But what happened with the family of Marquez? I cannot think of any reason that the Liasons would kill them, but their date of death is quite the coincidence. Did they die for some other supernatural reason?